# Rails 4 create multiple records of same model in one form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to create multiple records for the same model at once (Rails 4.1.2), but the form is only sending the controller one set of parameter values (actually only the first row) ...

Basically I have a form in my index view to add more records by just clicking on the + sign (using javascript to append the table rows) to add more rows of record at once...and hitting submit to create them all at once.

Here is what I have so far in my view:

```
 <div class="table-responsive">
   <table class="table equipment-table" id="EquipmentTable">
     <thead>
       <tr>
         <th>Equipment name</th>
         <th>Serial number</th>
         <th>Date out warehouse</th>
         <th>Date in warehouse</th>
         <th>Technician</th>
         <th>Site location</th>
         <th>Date in</th>
         <th>Date out</th>
         <th>Technician return</th>
       </tr>
     </thead>

     <tbody id="tableToModify">
       <% @equipments.each do |equipment| %>
       <tr>
         <td><%= equipment.equipment_name %></td>
         <td><%= equipment.serial_number %></td>
         <td><%= equipment.date_out_warehouse %></td>
         <td><%= equipment.date_in_warehouse %></td>
         <td><%= equipment.technician %></td>
         <td><%= equipment.site_location %></td>
         <td><%= equipment.date_in %></td>
         <td><%= equipment.date_out %></td>
         <td><%= equipment.technician_return %></td>
       </tr>
       <% end %>

       <%= form_tag make_multiple_equipments_path, method: :post do %>

          <tr class="equipment_row" id="rowToClone">
          <%= fields_for "equipments[]", @equipment do |f| %>
            <td><%= f.text_field :equipment_name, size: 15 %></td>
            <td><%= f.text_field :serial_number, size: 7 %></td>
            <td><%= f.date_field :date_out_warehouse %></td>
            <td><%= f.date_field :date_in_warehouse %></td>
            <td><%= f.text_field :technician, size: 12 %></td>
            <td><%= f.text_field :site_location, size: 12 %></td>
            <td><%= f.date_field :date_in %></td>
            <td><%= f.date_field :date_out %></td>
            <td><%= f.text_field :technician_return, size: 15 %></td>
            <td><input type="button" id="delbutton" class="btn btn-danger" value=" - " onclick="deleteRow(this)"/></td>
          <% end %>
          </tr>

          </tbody>
          </table>

       <input type="button" onclick="cloneRow()" value=" + " class="btn btn-success"/>  
       <br>
       <%= submit_tag "Submit", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
       <% end %>
 </div>


 <script type="text/javascript">
    function deleteRow(row)
    {
      var i=row.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
      document.getElementById('EquipmentTable').deleteRow(i);
    }
    function cloneRow()
    {
      var row = document.getElementById("rowToClone"); // find row to copy
      var table = document.getElementById("tableToModify"); // find table to append to
      var clone = row.cloneNode(true); // copy children too
      table.appendChild(clone); // add new row to end of table
    }
 </script>
```

Here is what I have in my controller (One job has many equipments):

```
def index
  @job = Job.find(params[:job_id])
  @equipments = @job.equipments.all
  @equipment = Equipment.new(:date_out_warehouse => Time.now, :date_in_warehouse => Time.now, :date_in => Time.now, :date_out => Time.now)
end

def make_multiple_equipments
  @job = Job.find(params[:job_id])
  count = 0
  equipments_array = params.permit(equipments: [:equipment_name, :serial_number, :date_out_warehouse, :date_in_warehouse, :technician, :site_location, :date_in, :date_out, :technician_return]).require(:equipments)

  while count < equipments_array.count
    @job.equipments.create(equipments_array[count])
    count = count + 1
  end

  redirect_to job_equipment_index_path(@job), :notice => 'Equipment were successfully created.'
end
```

These are my params :

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
"authenticity_token"=>"TdHJAFI+Vw5zxFKDNXbx7LHPcT2mJ4BBg04Qt0Z9QNY=",
"equipments"=>[{"equipment_name"=>"tester",
"serial_number"=>"29",
"date_out_warehouse"=>"2014-08-04",
"date_in_warehouse"=>"2014-08-04",
"technician"=>"paul",
"site_location"=>"steve",
"date_in"=>"2014-08-04",
"date_out"=>"2014-08-04",
"technician_return"=>"mark"}],
"commit"=>"Submit",
"job_id"=>"2"}
```

If any one can provide me some insight it would be greatly appreciated ...

**Update 1:**
I seem to think the problem is in the form as it is not sending an array with more than one item I changed the form as below but still in the parameters its only sending one set of values:

```
<td><%= text_field_tag "equipments[][equipment_name]" %></td>
<td><%= text_field_tag "equipments[][serial_number]" %></td>
<td><%= date_field_tag "equipments[][date_out_warehouse]" %></td>
<td><%= date_field_tag "equipments[][date_in_warehouse]" %></td>
<td><%= text_field_tag "equipments[][technician]" %></td>
<td><%= text_field_tag "equipments[][site_location]" %></td>
<td><%= date_field_tag "equipments[][date_in]" %></td>
<td><%= date_field_tag "equipments[][date_out]" %></td>
<td><%= text_field_tag "equipments[][technician_return]" %></td>
```

**Parameters:**

```
 {"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"oX6niXZFQQzoomlsojYweAuXtiLjP7LCdKGhOvUe/Vw=",
 "equipments"=>[{"equipment_name"=>"boot",
 "serial_number"=>"23",
 "date_out_warehouse"=>"2014-08-08",
 "date_in_warehouse"=>"2014-08-08",
 "technician"=>"paul",
 "site_location"=>"steve",
 "date_in"=>"",
 "date_out"=>"",
 "technician_return"=>"frank"}],
 "commit"=>"Submit",
 "job_id"=>"3"}
```

Comment: Hi codingbear. Have you tried to do it _The Rails Way_ instead of manually managing the `equipments` creation? http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#building-complex-forms It looks like `accepts_nested_attributes_for` would be the right tool for this job.

Comment: Hi @YanisVieilly I checked it out and even read the new rails 4 guide regarding forms here http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html Section 7.2 - Combining Them that talks about Array parameters, but no of no help...

Answer (score 0):

The only problem is in your js clone function:

```
function cloneRow()
{
  var row = document.getElementById("rowToClone"); // find row to copy
  var tableForm = document.getElementById("tableToModify").getElementsByTagName("form"); // find table to append to
  var clone = row.cloneNode(true); // copy children too
  tableForm.appendChild(clone); // add new row to end of table
}
```

You should append the cloned row in the form and not just in the parent table. I got the form with `getElementsByTagName` but maybe you should consider add an `id` to your form.